# Ajax.Request Parameters Serialize(true) not working on IE9

Tags: ajax, serialization, parameters, request, prototypejs

I have a problem on a site. I the following code:

```
<form id="AddNewProduct" action="" method="post">
 <fieldset id="AddReleaseFieldset" runat="server" class="addrelease subform">
<legend>Release Details</legend>
```

After that all the fields. And the javascript has something like this:

```
new Ajax.Request('Product/Add.async', {
  parameters:$('AddNewProduct').serialize(true),
  onSuccess....
```

The problem is that on my async code when I debug, If I use any browser I am receiving all the parameters with the correct values:
Name="Pablo" LastName="Mur"
But on IE9 they are all null.
Name=null Lastname=null
What could be wrong, I try getting the fieldset off, in case the serialize doesn't find the fields, but is the same, I don't wanna pass each field because there are so many, but if there is no other way I will do, why could be that the serialize is not working.
How can I solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't the selector be $('#AddNewProduct')? I don't know if that is just a typo or if that could be the problem of why it's not working.

Comment: This is prototype, and with # it doesn't work neither on Chrome nor IE9.

Comment: Was a <p /> before the <form> that was making that the IE9 act weird and takes the fieldset as out of the <form>, solved.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, i had the same issue in IE9, there was

```
<p>
  &nbsp;
```

just before the

so the form.serialize and form.request wasn't working